# Opaque OpenGL textures have transparent border

Tags: opengl, transparency, textures

My problem concerns rendering text with OpenGL -- the text is rendered into a texture, and then drawn onto a quad. The trouble is that the pixels on the edge of the texture are drawn partially transparent. The interior of the texture is fine.

I'm calculating the texture coordinates to hit the center of my texels, using NEAREST (non-)interpolation, setting the texture wrapping to CLAMP_TO_EDGE, and setting the projection matrix to place my vertices at the center of the viewport pixels. Still seeing the issue.

I'm working on VTK with their texture utilities. These are the GL calls that are used to load the texture, as determined by stepping through with a debugger:

```
glGenTextures(1, &id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
// Create and bind pixel buffer object here (not shown, lots of indirection in VTK)...
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 , GL_RGBA, xsize, ysize, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
// Unbind PBO -- also omitted
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
glAlphaFunc (GL_GREATER, static_cast<GLclampf>(0));
glEnable (GL_ALPHA_TEST);
// I've also tried doing this here for premultiplied alpha, but it made no difference:
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadIdentity();
```

The rendering code:

```
  float p[2] = ...; // point to render text at

  int imgDims[2] = ...; // Actual dimensions of image
  float width = ...; // Width of texture in image
  float height = ...; // Height of texture in image

  // Prepare the quad
  float xmin = p[0];
  float xmax = xmin + width - 1;
  float ymin = p[1];
  float ymax = ymin + height - 1;
  float quad[] = { xmin, ymin,
                   xmax, ymin,
                   xmax, ymax,
                   xmin, ymax };

  // Calculate the texture coordinates.
  float smin = 1.0f / (2.0f * (imgDims[0]));
  float smax = (2.0 * width - 1.0f) / (2.0f * imgDims[0]);
  float tmin = 1.0f / (2.0f * imgDims[1]);
  float tmax = (2.0f * height - 1.0f) / (2.0f * imgDims[1]);

  float texCoord[] = { smin, tmin,
                       smax, tmin,
                       smax, tmax,
                       smin, tmax };

  // Set projection matrix to map object coords to pixel centers
  // (modelview is identity)
  GLint vp[4];
  glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, vp);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glPushMatrix();
  glLoadIdentity();
  float offset = 0.5;
  glOrtho(offset, vp[2] + offset,
          offset, vp[3] + offset,
          -1, 1);

  // Disable polygon smoothing. Why not, I've tried everything else?
  glDisable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);

  // Draw the quad
  glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 255);
  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
  glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, points);
  glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoord);
  glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
  glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
  glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

  // Restore projection matrix
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glPopMatrix();
```

For debugging purposes, I've overwritten the outermost texels with red, and the next inner layer of texels with green (otherwise it's hard to see what's going on in the mostly-white text image).

I've inspected the texture in-memory using gDEBugger, and it looks as expected -- bright red and green borders around the texture area (the extra empty space is padding to make its size a power of two). For reference:

[image: Good pixels!]

Here's what the final rendered image looks like (magnified 20x -- the black pixels are remnants of the text that was rendered under the debugging borders). Pale red border, but still a bold green inner border:

[image: Bad pixels!]

So it is just the outer edge of pixels that is affected. I'm not sure if it's color-blending or alpha-blending that's screwing things up, I'm at a loss. I've noticed that the corner pixels are twice as pale as the edge pixels, perhaps that's significant... Maybe someone here can spot the error?

Comment: If something is showing up as "transparent", it must be because of a blend mode. So what blending mode are you using?

Comment: Also, you say that you're using CLAMP_TO_EDGE and so forth, but you don't show the code. Are you sure you're setting it right?

Comment: I'm working on VTK and using their texture class, so I omitted most of that. I went back and stepped through the texture initialization and added the GL calls to the post. The only part I've omitted now is the initialization of a PBO, which shouldn't be an issue because the data is being uploaded to graphics memory without problems (as evidenced by the gDEBugger screenshot).

Comment: Are you rendering with any AA turned on? Because you're only rendering half the edge pixels, so if you have AA, it'll do something like that. If you removed the half pixel offset from the texture coordinates, you could get rid of it from the vertices too, everything would cancel nicely and the code would be cleaner and the rendering more predictable.

Comment: (one of the reasons I suspect there might be additional processing happening is because the edge pixels here have been gamma corrected, but I see no mention of that in the code posted)

Answer (score 0):

Could be a "pixel perfect" problem. OpenGL defines the center of a line to be the spot that gets rasterized into a pixel. The middle is exactly half way between 1 integer and the next... to get pixel (x,y) to display "pixel perfect"... fix up your coordinates to be:

```
x=(int)x+0.5f; // x is a float.. makes 0.0 into 0.5, 16.343 into 16.5, etc. 
y=(int)y+0.5f;
```

This probably is what is messing up the blending. I had the same issues with texture modulating... a single somewhat dimmer line or series of pixels at the bottom and right edges.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've worked on it for the last few days. There were few ideas that didn't work at all. The only one that worked is to admit that this "Perfect Pixel" exists and try to trick it. Bad That I can't vote up for your answer Cosmic Bacon. But your answer, even if it looks good -- will a little bit ruin everything in a special programs like Games. My answer -- is improved yours.

Here's the solution:

Step1: Make a method that draws texture that you need and use only it for drawing. And Add 0.5f to every coordinate. Look:

```
public void render(Texture tex,float x1,float y1,float x2,float y2)
{
    tex.bind();
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x1+0.5f,y1+0.5f);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x2+0.5f,y1+0.5f);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x2+0.5f,y2+0.5f);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x1+0.5f,y2+0.5f);
    GL11.glEnd();
}
```

Step2: If you're going to use "glTranslatef(somethin1,somethin2,0)" it will be nice to make a method that overcomes "Translatef" and doesn't let camera to move on fractional distance. Cause if there will be a little chance that Camera moves on, let's say, 0.3 -- Sooner or later you'll see this issue again(multiple times, i suppose). Next code makes camera follow the Object that has X and Y. And Camera will never loose the object from it's sight:

```
public void LookFollow(Block AF)
{
    float some=5;//changing me will cause camera to move faster/slower
    float mx=0,my=0;

    //Right-Left
    if(LookCorX!=AF.getX())
    {
        if(AF.getX()>LookCorX)
        {
            if(AF.getX()<LookCorX+2)
                mx=AF.getX()-LookCorX;
            if(AF.getX()>LookCorX+2)
                mx=(AF.getX()-LookCorX)/some;
        }
        if(AF.getX()<LookCorX)
        {
            if(2+AF.getX()>LookCorX)
                mx=AF.getX()-LookCorX;
            if(2+AF.getX()<LookCorX)
                mx=(AF.getX()-LookCorX)/some;
        }
    }

    //Up-Down
    if(LookCorY!=AF.getY())
    {
        if(AF.getY()>LookCorY)
        {
            if(AF.getY()<LookCorY+2)
                my=AF.getY()-LookCorY;
            if(AF.getY()>LookCorY+2)
                my=(AF.getY()-LookCorY)/some;
        }
        if(AF.getY()<LookCorY)
        {
            if(2+AF.getY()>LookCorY)
                my=AF.getY()-LookCorY;
            if(2+AF.getY()<LookCorY)
                my=(AF.getY()-LookCorY)/some;
        }
    }

    //Evading "Perfect Pixel"
    mx=(int)mx;
    my=(int)my;

    //Moving Camera
    GL11.glTranslatef(-mx,-my,0);

    //Saving up Position of camera.
    LookCorX+=mx;
    LookCorY+=my;
}
float LookCorX=300,LookCorY=200; //camera's starting position
```

As the result -- we receive a camera that moves a little sharper, cause steps can't be less than 1 pixel, and sometimes, it's necessary to make a smaller step, but textures are looking okay, and, it's -- a Great Progress!

Sorry for a real Big Answer. I'm still working on a Good Solution. Once I'll find something better and shorter -- this will be erased by me.

Comment: This comment was generated automatically during review. Stackoverflow is Q&A site, not a forum. So, if you have question, you need to create a new one clicking on "Ask question". You can also make link to this question, if it contain essential part of your problem. Your answer will be deleted sooner or later accordingly to the rules.

Comment: Oh, man. I am looking for an answer here. Your rules sucks! We can delete all of useless things in here, but once my post has a piece of information -- let's keep it for a while! I'm not running for the "reputation". I have One Trouble, and I'm looking Good over the posts I make. Trust me, I will clean all of the rubbish I made once the "deal" will be done.

Comment: And yeah, thanks to you, guys, I've got blocked from answering. Looks like you're more bothered with building a good community instead of looking for answers. Keep On, You're Doing It Right!

Comment: I don't know what's up with the people casting invalid flags on this answer, but the point about fractional translation is an important one.  The new revision of the answer is a lot better, but the point was there even in the first.